If the minimal polynomial $\bmod p$ is irreducible, is $(p)$ prime?
In a number field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ with minimal polynomial $m_\theta(t)$, is it true that for an ideal $p\mathcal{O}_K$, where $\mathcal{O}_K$ are the algebraic integers over $K$, that when $m_\theta(t)$ is irreducible modulo $p$, we have that $p\mathcal{O}_K$ is prime? If so, why is this the case?
For context, I am showing for $\theta=\sqrt{m}$, for a square-free integer $m$, what the prime factorisation of $2\mathcal{O}_K$ is. In one of the cases of $m$ I get that the minimal polynomial is irreducible modulo $2$, and I know by a different source that, in this case, $(2)$ is prime, and I am wondering if this follows from what I stated above, and if so, if this is true in general.

Maybe the proposition in this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/777822 answer is useful.

This follows from the Dedekind-Kummer theorem. In general, you have to assume that $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\theta]$, but if $p$ doesn't divide the index $[\mathcal{O}_K : \mathbb{Z}[\theta]]$, then considering the minimal polynomial for $\theta$ still gives the right answer. See these notes by Keith Conrad for details: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/dedekindf.pdf .

@ViktorVaughn Oh wow, as I was trying to explain why it still was not clear to me, I realized that in the case of the problem, we get $(p)=P_1$ for a prime ideal $P_1$, and so $(p)$ is of course prime. The way Dedekind-Kummer is stated in our notes, is a bit different than in the notes you linked (which I did read before, but disregarded the exact statement of the theorem). Thanks!
